# Pyinstaller: save space when compiling

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using PyInstaller to generate an exe of a .py file I have created.

The issue is that it generates a folder of 70mb which is a lot.

Is there a way to save space? For instance in the dist folder I find the following sub-folders: are `tcl` and `tk` packages; do they need to be there or are they not functional and might be removed?

Do you have any suggestion to reduce the size?

[image]

In general, are there best practices to save space while compiling?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#spec-file-operation), you can pass an 'excludes' parameter in the spec file:

```
block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['minimal.py'],
     pathex=['/Developer/PItests/minimal'],
     binaries=None,
     datas=None,
     hiddenimports=[],
     hookspath=None,
     runtime_hooks=None,
     excludes=None,
     cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
     cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,... )
coll = COLLECT(...)
```